# Given that $5$ is a primitive root of $73$, find all solutions to $x^3 - 1 ≡ 0$ (mod $73$).

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

I'm working through some problems with primitive roots and needed some help on this problem, specifically how do we use the fact that $5$ is a primitive root to solve this?

Given:  $5$ is a primitive root of $73$, find all solutions to $x^3 - 1 ≡ 0$ (mod $73$).

Thanks!

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html

Comment: @labbhattacharjee But we are trying to _find_ $a$ (as described in that link). So the discrete logarithm is answering the wrong question.

Comment: @Arthur, Please find my answer below

Answer (score 2):

From the fact that $5$ is a primitive root, we know that $5$ has order $72$ in the multiplicative group. Let $a = 5^{24}$. Can you tell me the order of $a$ modulo $73$? What about the order of $a^2$, what about the order of $a^3$?

Comment: I'm getting order a mod 73 as 8 and the order of a^2 and a^3 as 9. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @Kami You have $a \mod 73=8$, which is a totally different answer to what the order $a$ (8) has mod 73.

Comment: The order of 64 (mod 73) would be 3 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html)

$3$ind$_5x\equiv0\pmod{\phi(73)}$

$\iff$ind$_5x\equiv0\pmod{24}\implies$ind$_5x=24k,x\equiv5^{24k}\pmod{73}$

But $0\le$ind$_5x<72\implies0\le k<3$